# toggle on/off hyperref options in document

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, links

Using the package `hyperref` I want to toggle on and off a certain option at different places in the document.

To be specific: I want to use the `frenchlinks` option, but disable that for the table of contents. The toc should be still linked nonetheless, but with another option of my choice preferably.

Another way of thinking of it might be to use `frenchlinks` exclusively for cross-references, if that is easier to realize it would be even better.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[hidelinks,frenchlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Einleitung}\label{sec:intro}
Text. \autoref{sec:intro}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no option, the commands are set at begin document. You will have to redefine an internal command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[hidelinks,frenchlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\makeatletter
\def\Hy@colorlink#1{\begingroup}%
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\section{Einleitung}\label{sec:intro}
Text. \autoref{sec:intro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Do you know if it's possible to set up the ``frenchlink`` style only for a certain type of link? Like it's possible to have different colors for cross-references and URL's for instance.